# How do I use CSS to cross fade between images?

Tags: html, css, transition

I followed a tutorial exactly and instead of fading from the Print_tab.png to the Print_tab_hover.png,
it just fades to white. Any way I could fix this (without using javascript)?.

Here is the code i Used:

HTML:

```
    <div id="print"
     <img class="bottom" src="images/print_tab_hover.png"  />
     <img class="top" src="images/print_tab.png"  />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #print {
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 169px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #print img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #print img.top:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine to me - see test here http://dabblet.com/gist/2818078 Make sure you have `<div id="print">` in your HTML, not `<div id="print"` as you've written here.

Comment: Wow. What a rookie mistake. I'm usually good at catching things like that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not working in Firefox; still fades to white.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#print {
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(http://fc06.deviantart.net/images2/i/2004/07/e/7/Firefox_dock_icon.png);
}

#print img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#print img.top:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

<div id="print">
   <img class="top" src="http://lanscaping-ideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Landscape-Paintings-2.jpg"  />
</div>
```

Just set a default background for the #print and fade over the new image, or vise versa.